# How to add tags to files on disk?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, storage

I'm creating app for cataloging images on disk. And looking for solution how to store data about tags I added to this images. For now I found only two solutions:

1. using information in DB. Since I use it in https://electronjs.org, I think better to make array with this information
2. usinf tags in exif.

My questions are:

1. what solution will be faster (it can be thousands of images on disk)?
2. Is there other solutions to add tags to images and store it?